# Extract Arabic Text From PDF WITH JAVA

Tags: java, eclipse, pdf, ocr

I want to extract text from a pdf, but the problem is that with Arabic text I just get some codes.

It works with French text.

This is my source code:

```
package com.example;

import java.io.*;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.OutputKeys;
import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMSource;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.*;
import org.apache.pdfbox.text.PDFTextStripper;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;

public class convert2 {

  static void WriteFromPDFToXML(String XMLFile, String content) {
    try {
      BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

      DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
      DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
      Document document = db.parse(XMLFile);

      //root
      System.out.println(document.getDocumentElement().getNodeName());

      //no of elemnts
      NodeList nodeList = document.getElementsByTagName("IndexValue");
      System.out.println(nodeList.getLength());

      for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {
        //insert an extra node for the second person
        if (i == 14) {
          Node node = nodeList.item(i);

          Element publisherElm = document.createElement("Value");

          // System.out.println("Enter publisher value :");
          //String publisher = br.readLine();

          publisherElm.appendChild(document.createTextNode(content));

          node.appendChild(publisherElm);
        }
      }

      TransformerFactory tff = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
      Transformer transformer = tff.newTransformer();

      transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.ENCODING, "UTF-8");
      transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");

      DOMSource xmlSource = new DOMSource(document);
      StreamResult outputTarget = new StreamResult(XMLFile);
      transformer.transform(xmlSource, outputTarget);
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

  static void DeleteFile(File output) {
    try {
      File file = output;
      if (file.delete()) {
        System.out.println(file.getName() + " is deleted!");
      } else {
        System.out.println("Delete operation is failed.");
      }
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    PDDocument pd;
    BufferedWriter wr;
    File output = null;
    String content;
    try {
      File input =
          new File(
              "C:/Users/HP/Desktop/EXPORT1/00000002.pdf"); // The PDF file from where you would like to extract
      output =
          new File(
              "C:/Users/HP/Desktop/EXPORT1/verif.txt"); // The text file where you are going to store the extracted data
      pd = PDDocument.load(input);
      System.out.println(pd.getNumberOfPages());
      System.out.println(pd.isEncrypted());
      pd.save("CopyOfInvoice.pdf"); // Creates a copy called "CopyOfInvoice.pdf"
      PDFTextStripper stripper = new PDFTextStripper();

      wr = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(output)));
      stripper.writeText(pd, wr);
      System.out.println(stripper.getText(pd));
      content = stripper.getText(pd);

      if (pd != null) {
        pd.close();
      }

      // I use close() to flush the stream.
      wr.close();
      DeleteFile(output);
      String test = Jsoup.parse(content).text();
      WriteFromPDFToXML("C:/Users/HP/Desktop/EXPORT1/result1.xml", test);

    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: How does this relate to either Eclipse or OCR?  Also, can you please show the input that you're providing to this, the output that you're expecting, and the output that you're actually getting?  Please, not a large file - just a line or two so that we can see what's going on.

Comment: In Input i have a scanned pdf document with arabic text
Output : I ijj..l\„-l,„o,.JI ~J l,i:rj.âa,..J) o„,-i..o.Æ If I I, l.JI f Lu ..CJjy ^••-J

Comment: *"arabic text Output : I ijj..l\„-l,„o,.JI ~J l,i:rj.âa,..J) o„,-i..o.Æ If I I, l.JI f Lu ..CJjy ^••-J"* - to me this does not exactly look Arabic. If this text extraction output already looks that broken, why don't you start by finding out why it is broken (or at least looks so) instead of wondering why some other code does not mysteriously heal the damage?

Comment: this happend just with arabic text i think cause the pdf file isn't scanned correctly

Comment: Well, we can't try to reproduce this if you don't supply your input.  However, what tool are you using to look at your output?  Is it possible that your output is correct, but the tool you're using to display it is messing it up?